# Updating a session in a web forms site from sub MVC site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Let me paint an ugly picture.

The primary application I maintain is written in C#, webforms. Any new development I carry out is done in MVC, EF, etc.

So 90% of the site is still in webforms, 10% MVC.

The webforms site uses certain user controls to select the item the user wants information for. Think of it as an event, they select event 1, then all pages display information for that event. These settings/selections are held in a cookie and/or session variable.

My issue is, I am slowly converting the site to MVC and so I need to be able to update the selected event from the MVC view, but have that selection "known" in the webforms site.

Both are 2 different codebases.

The webforms code which updates the event is:

```
Admin.AdminSession.GetCurrent().EventID = selectedEventID;
```

GetCurrent() returns this

```
get { return (AdminSession)HttpContext.Current.Session["AdminSession.Current"]; }
```

But my MVC app cannot seem to read from the session. I have tried

```
HttpContext.Session["AdminSession.Current"];
```

and

```
this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["AdminSession.Current"];
```

But both yield null

So, is there a way to read a session from a sub app? For context, the hierarchy is like this

rootsite.com (webforms)
rootsite.com/subfolder (mvc project)

Comment: As far as I know, you read session variable like this: `HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionVariableName"]`... this is the same for both MVC and WebForms... are yo sure you are populating the session correctly? Your read seems correct to me.

Comment: Are they 2 separate sites on one domain or 1 site running both forms and MVC? If 1 site, I'd not use session on the MVC side. Store the value in a cookie and read that value on both sides. If the cookie is lost, intervene and get the user to re-select the value again. If it is 2 sites, I don't think you can use session like this

Comment: Session is definitely there @HoomanBahreini 
scgough they are on the same domain, the MVC is just in a directory below the root.